# Multiple linear regression model along with ensemble ggplot in R?

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, tidyverse, predict

I am trying to `predict` June - September `Level` for the `Year 2020` using a `multiple linear regression model`. In my example below, I assume that the year 2016 conditions will repeat and use it for predicting June-Sep Level for the 2020. I `plot` the observed Level up until `May 31`, shown as solid black line and   the `Forecasted Level` shown as dashed blue line.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1500)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "days"),
                 Level = runif(6940, 360, 366), Flow = runif(6940, 1,10),
                 PCP = runif(6940, 0,25), MeanT = runif(6940, 1, 30)) %>% 
                  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>% 
                  filter(between(Month, 6, 9))
Model <- lm(data = DF, Level~Flow+PCP+MeanT)
Yr_2016 <- DF %>%
  filter(Year == 2016) %>% 
  select(c(3:5)) 
Pred2020 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-06-01"), to = as.Date("2020-9-30"), by = "days"),
                       Forecast = predict(Model, Yr_2016))
  
Obs2020 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-05-31"), by = "days"),
                      Level = runif(152, 360, 366))

ggplot(data = Obs2020, aes(x = Date, y = Level), col = "black")+
  geom_line(size = 2)+
  geom_line(data = Pred2020, aes(x = Date, y = Forecast), linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

**My goal**

I want to use the `fitted model` to `predic`t June - Sep for the year `2020` assuming that all the years in `DF` will repeat itself (not just the year 2016) and then have a `plot` where all the years `Forecasted` scenarios (June -Sep) are shown in different colours - something like below

[image]

Comment: To clarify, the graph should show the forcast of the years 2017, 2018, 2019 and 2020 based on the model of 2016, correct?

Comment: The ‘Model’ be used for forecasting all the years of ‘DF’

Comment: You use the 2016 data from June to September as input in your prediction for 2020. If you use 2016 for all other years, they will basically yield the same prediction. Or did I understand something wrong?

Comment: Thanks @TimTeaFan, Sorry for the confusion. I do not want the model be build for each year. I have Observed data for Jan-May of 2020 which is reflected in `Obs2020`. I assumed that the `2016` conditions will repeat from Jun-Sep so i used it in the `Pred2020`. I want to use all the years not just 2016 in `Pred2020` to give me all the possibilities for Jun-Sep. I.e. for `Year_2010`, I will replace the `Year_2016` with Year_2010 in `Pred2020`.

Comment: Ok, I revised my answer. Not sure if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**new answer**

The code below should do what you are looking for (if I understood it correctly). The graph, however, is still chaotic.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1500)

DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), to = as.Date("2018-12-31"), by = "days"),
                 Level = runif(6940, 360, 366), Flow = runif(6940, 1,10),
                 PCP = runif(6940, 0,25), MeanT = runif(6940, 1, 30)) %>% 
  mutate(Year = year(Date), Month = month(Date), Day = day(Date)) %>% 
  filter(between(Month, 6, 9))

Model <- lm(data = DF, Level ~ Flow + PCP + MeanT)

Obs2020 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-01-01"),
                                 to = as.Date("2020-05-31"),
                                 by = "days"),
                      Level = runif(152, 362.7, 363.25))
pred_data <- DF %>% 
  nest_by(Year) %>% 
  mutate(pred_df = list(tibble(Date = seq(as.Date("2020-06-01"),
                                          to = as.Date("2020-09-30"),
                                          by = "days"),
                               Forecast = predict(.env$Model, data)))) %>%
  select(Year, pred_df) %>% 
  unnest(pred_df) 

ggplot(data = Obs2020, aes(x = Date, y = Level), col = "black") +
  geom_line(size = 0.1) +
  geom_line(data = pred_data,
            aes(x = Date, y = Forecast, group = factor(Year), color = factor(Year)),
            size = 0.1)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-06-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>